# How to trigger ajax loading with an observable varariable in knockout?

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

I got some tabs in a page. When clicking on a tab, the `currentTab` changes its value, which should trigger an ajax loading of a new tab content.

The concept is similar to a `ko.computed`, which however, only update another variable as the value change takes place.

Is there any function we can use to observe the change of `currentTab` and load the different tab content page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`subscribe` method](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) of an observable:

```
vm.currentTab.subscribe(function(newValue) {
   //currentTab has just changed value, to newValue
   //You can fire your Ajax call here.
});
```